# Change diff font in GitKraken

Tags: fonts, settings, diff, apl, gitkraken

I program APL and have been considering switching from SourceTree to GitKraken. However, I have been unable to change the diff view font. As the font is pretty essential to APL, this is holding my move back.

Is there a way to change font face (and size) in GitKraken?

Both official an hacky answers are welcome.

SourceTree, using the APL385 Unicode font, size 16:
[image: SourceTree screenshot]

GitKraken, using the default font:
[image: GitKraken screenshot]

For comparison, here is Stack Overflow's rendering:

```
c←⊃chunk
(c1 c2)←{⍵{(1,1↓<\⍵)⊂⍺}'::'⍷⍵}c
c2←#.Strings.deb 2↓c2
c2←c2{0∊⍴⍺:⍵ ⋄ 0∊⍴⍵:⊂⍺ ⋄ (⊂⍺),⍵}1↓chunk
c2←¯2↓∊c2,¨⊂⎕UCS 13 10
r⍪←c1 c2
```

Comment: I'm wrestling with the same concern, hopefully somebody will provide a resolution eventually.  I would also have tended towards GitKracken rather than SourceTree if not for this concern, but now I'm leaning towards SourceTree.

Comment: @cdahms Version 2.0 has a vastly better font, but still no choice. I keep complaining about this every time they ask for feedback. Do the same, and maybe they'll hear us eventually!

Comment: I have a problem with last version in Arch Linux, in open file manager all fonts are wrong.

Comment: @cdahms See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53589196/5306507) that this has been resolved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While Axosoft usually make a big deal about enhancements to GitKraken, this essential one went unnoticed. GitKraken 4.1.1 allows you to choose font and size freely, and renders them very nicely too:

[image: GitKraken 4.1.1 diff]

It isn't even so easy to find the options. Go to Preferences > Editor Preferences:

[image: Preferences > Editor Preferences]

Comment: weird, when I first looked at this the UI showed 0
EDIT: ah, it starts at 0

Comment: Need to call out that once you customise editor font, you may have issue with cursor position in-app merge output editor. Basically the customized font width may mess up the cursor position, make you not be able to know where the text will be inserted.

Comment: The "Editor Preferences" option doesn't exist any more and I can't find this option under the new "UI Customization". How can I change GitKraken back to a monospaced font now?

Comment: @Jorn Sorry, I can't answer that. I now use GitHub Desktop instead, and it is quite easy to hack a font change into.

Answer (score 8):

This tip is not exactly about font but there's a zoom icon at the bottom right which allows to zoom in which I didn't notice initially. HTH.

Comment: I had no idea about zoom feature until I accidentally zoomed out to 80% and now I can't work anything higher as 100% font to me is too big!